Ejecutar consulta a base de datos
Estoy tratando de conectarme a sqlite con react native, he visto varios ejemplos pero ninguno me funciona, uso console.log pero en la parte donde hago transaction a la bd no entra, no sé cual sea el problema. Les dejo mi código esperando que puedan ayudarme.


import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import SQLite from "react-native-sqlite-storage";

export default function ListProducts(props: unknown) {
    const [names, setNames] = useState<string[]>([]); // Asegúrate de especificar el tipo correcto para names

    useEffect(() => {
        const initializeDatabase = async () => {
            try {
                const db = await SQLite.openDatabase({
                    name: "mydata.db",
                    createFromLocation: 1
                });

                console.log('Aqui si entra');//Aqui si recibo el console.log
                await db.transaction(async tx => {
                    console.log('transaction ha sido ejecutada');//no se muestra este console
                });
                db.transaction(tx => {
                    console.log('transaction2 ha sido ejecutada');//tampoco se muestra
                    // Crear la tabla si no existe
                    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT)');

                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error al abrir la base de datos:", error);
            }
        };

        initializeDatabase();
    }, []);

    return (
        // Renderiza tu componente aquí
        <View>
            {names.map((name, index) => (
                <Text key={index}>{name}</Text>
            ))}
        </View>
    );
}




Creo que lo que pasa es que no estás ejecutando bien el transaction, de donde viene el tx?
